# Mailchimp API form not sending final welcome email

Tags: php, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to build a custom form in my site using the `Mailchimp API`. I've managed to write up a `PHP` script which is adding my users to a mailing list from within the Mailchimp dashboard. However I'm having an issue sending them an auto responder email.

This is my `HTML` form:

```
<form method='post' action='<?= get_template_directory_uri() ?>/mailchimp.php'>
    <input type='text' name='email'/>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Subscribe'/>
</form>
```

This is my code that handles the request to Mailchimp and adds a user to a list:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    if(!empty($email) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
        // MailChimp API credentials
        $apiKey = 'xxx';
        $listID = 'xxx';

        // MailChimp API URL
        $memberID = md5(strtolower($email));
        $dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);
        $url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listID . '/members/' . $memberID;

        // member information
        $json = json_encode([
            'email_address' => $email,
            'status'        => 'subscribed'
        ]);

        // send a HTTP POST request with curl
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);

        echo "<h1>$httpCode</h1>";
        return $httpCode;

    }
}
```

I read that you cannot send a final welcome email to anyone unless they are marked as `subscribed` to your list. I understand Mailchimp enforces a double optin policy unless overriden using the API by setting the users status to subscribed as I've done below:

```
// member information
        $json = json_encode([
            'email_address' => $email,
            'status'        => 'subscribed'
        ]);
```

but for some reason I am still not receiving an email upon subscribing to the list. Would anyone have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong.

I've ensured from backend of Mailchimp that the Final Welcome Email is setup.

Answer (score 3):

I've managed to resolve my issue and I'm posting this answer here for anyone who may experience a similar problem to me regarding the sending of a welcome email by way of the single opt-in process.

**Double Opt In Process**

Mailchimp enforces a double opt-in policy whereby a user who signs up for your newsletter/service will be sent 2 emails. The first is a confirmation email which enables the user to confirm they requested to join your list. The second is a welcome email - only sent once the user is added to your list.

**Overriding the Double Opt in Process**

You can override this functionality by using the `Mailchimp API`. You must ensure that you add the user with the status of `subscribed` so that they do not have to go through the double opt-in process. However, this still will not mean that the welcome email is sent.

**Sending the Welcome Email**

In order to send this welcome email you must set up an Automation rule. This rule should contain a trigger which is fired immediately after a user subscribes to a list. You can set these rules up in the Mailchimp backend. By doing this you can then send welcome emails to subscribers via the single opt in process.

**Automation Rules**

Bear in mind that the Automation rule will only trigger once per email. So if someone were to unsubscribe or be deleted from the list and resubscribed with the same email no welcome email would be received.

**For Wordpress**

If you are using `Wordpress` a great `plugin` which handles the integration to Mailchimp is `Mailchimp for Wordpress`. However this on it's own won't work - you need to add the automation via your mailchimp account to send the welcome emails.

I hope this helps people in the future!